# Angular velocity and rotation matrices

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm running into some confusion understanding rotations as being instantaneous cross products of angular velocity vectors. I would like to highlight two approaches which seem like they contradict each other, in the hopes that somebody can explain the conceptual error being made.

**Approach 1**

Don't think about frames. Just imagine I have some vector rotating according to some rotation matrix $A(\omega t).$
$$\vec{r}(t) = A \vec{r_0}$$
$$ A^T \vec{r}(t) = \vec{r_0}$$
Now, I want to find how this changes with time.
$$\frac{d \vec{r}(t)}{dt} = \frac{dA}{dt} \vec{r_0}$$
$$\dot{\vec{r}(t)} = \dot{A} \vec{r_0}$$
$$\dot{\vec{r}(t)} = \dot{A}  A^T \vec{r}(t)$$
Now, it so happens that $\dot{A}  A^T $ is an antisymmetric matrix. So I can associate it with the cross product of some $\vec{\omega.}$
$$\dot{\vec{r}(t)} =\vec{ \omega} \times \vec{r}(t).$$
**Approach 2**

Now  think about frames.
We have the same rotation matrix which transforms a basis set $\vec{e}_j'=A_{ij} \vec{e}_i.$

Then for any vector $\vec{r}$ you have

$$\vec{r}=r_j' \vec{e}_j' = A_{ij} r_j' \vec{e}_i.$$

Now you look at how this changes with time

$$\dot{\vec{r}}=(A_{ij} \dot{r}_j' + \dot{A}_{ij} r_j') \vec{e}_i.$$

We put this in the components of the body-fixed frame

$$\dot{\vec{r}} = (A_{ij} \dot{r}_j' + \dot{A}_{ij} r_j') A_{ik} \vec{e}_k' = (\dot{r}_k' + \Omega_{kj} r_j') \vec{e}_k'.$$
In the case of a vector that is just rotating, this yields
$$\dot{r_i}\vec{e}_i= \dot{A}_{ij} A_{ik} r_j' \vec{e}_k' $$
But when we transform this back to the "space" system we get
$$\dot{\vec{r}(t)} =  A^T \dot{A} \vec{r}(t).$$
So why do I get that $\vec{\omega} =  \dot{A} A^T$ in the first approach, but $\vec{\omega} =  A^T \dot{A} $ in the second approach?

Comment: On further thought, I think I have made a mistake by using the same matrix for both an "active" and a "passive" rotation, and I neglected to take the transpose in one of the approaches. But I am not sure if this totally answers the question.

Comment: $ A^T \dot{A}$ is a matrix not vector

Comment: Yes, but because it is antisymmetric, you can say $A^T \dot{A} \vec{r} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ for some $ \vec{\omega}.$

Comment: I am having a hard time following all the indices on the second approach. I do know the first approach leads to the correct result.